# Can't create resource group in lite account

Tags: ibm-cloud

For some reason I cannot create a resource group for IBM cloud. The error says I can only create one resource group in a lite account. But unfortunately I do not have any group in there

[image: Error in IBM Cloud]

Could someone give some advice how I should deal with that challenge?

Answer (score 0):

When you open and activate your account, a resource group named "default" is created automatically. You cannot create another one while on lite/free plan. You would need to upgrade. 
You can verify the default resource group under : `Manage -> Account -> Resource groups`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Manoj! The default group has not been created (you can see this in the background of my shared picture). Is there anything I could do to trigger the creation again? Currently I do have 0 ressouce groups associated with my account.

Comment: Thats very strange. What do u see in the Resource Group drop down on dashboard? I have added one more image in above answer. You have to raise a bug or support request to IBM.